# Google play issue: Violation of Permissions policy

Tags: android, google-play

For months I've been trying to publish an app with READ_CALL_LOG permission to no avail.

App is a contact management app including scheduled meetings, calendar and other events.
I only need to be able to get incoming call number, but since it's not allowed, I've implemented full InCallService that launches activity to display calling window with common answer/hang up buttons and few that redirect to our main app.

I've updated **"App content**" section **"Sensitive app permissions"** with checked **"Default phone handler"**, provided instructions for review.

Latest version of the app is deployed in internal track. But I also have older rejected versions in beta, alpha and production tracks

App itself on first launch asks permissions to become a default Call App, otherwise won't even start.

And yet, no matter how much I try, I keep getting **"App rejected"** in Play store **"Policy status"** section. Going to see further details I get:

> Issue: Violation of Permissions policy    After reviewing your app, we
> found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the
> following reason(s): Requested permissions do not match core
> functionality of the app You declared Default Phone handler (and any
> other core functionality usage while default handler) as the core
> functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your
> app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about
> permitted uses and exceptions. Please either: • Make changes to your
> app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core
> functionality or, • Select a use case that matches your app’s
> functionality

With **"Eligibility issue"** below:

> Sensitive permission Your app does not qualify for use of the
> requested permissions. Permission requests should make sense to users.
> You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement
> critical current features or services in your application. You may not
> use permissions that give access to user or device data for
> undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes.

To my understanding if I declare the intent of using app as a default phone call handler and make that explicitly clear to the user I should be able to publish this app? Being able to detect call number is a core functionality for the app.

I've tried reaching out to support multiple times, but they just write, that they'll contact me via email to never be heard from again.

Any suggestions on what could be improved?

Comment: good place to start  - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-sms-call-log-permissions%2Calternatives-to-common-uses

Comment: please fill Permissions Declaration Form on above link if your app is in line with google play policy. Once you get approval from above form, you can submit the app and it will pass

Comment: @AmodGokhale, I read that page multiple times, and as I said, I completed permission declaration form by selecting "Default Phone Handler" and providing instructions for testing. Yet after multiple days I still got rejected.

Comment: if permission declaring approval is rejected, app will not be approved

Comment: @AmodGokhale, I know, but how am I supposed what needs to be changed?